# Update one DataTable from another

Tags: linq, datatable

```
create table employee
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10),
    dept_id int,
    dept_name varchar(10)
);

insert into employee values(1, 'ABC1', 1, '');
insert into employee values(2, 'ABC2', 2, '');
insert into employee values(3, 'ABC3', 1, '');
insert into employee values(4, 'ABC4', 2, '');
insert into employee values(5, 'ABC5', 1, '');

create table dept
(
    dept_id int,
    dept_name varchar(10)
);

insert into dept values(1, 'XYZ1');
insert into dept values(2, 'XYZ2');
```

```
UPDATE e
SET    e.dept_name = d.dept_name
FROM   employee AS e
       JOIN dept AS d
       ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id
```

How do I convert above query (in bold letters) to a LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can. Linq to SQL is meant as a means to get data in/out of your database for use in your application code. What you want here is a lower-level data manipulation, which is best done in T-SQL as your example shows.

You could load the records from both tables using a join into a different object, then iterate the results.

```
// I'm doing this this way because I can't remember the syntax for 
// LoadOptions and want to be sure to avoid the SELECT N+1 issue.
var query = from e in db.Employees
            select new EmployeeDepartment
                       {
                           Employee = e,
                           Department = e.Department
                       };

foreach (var item in query)
{
    item.Employee.DepartmentName = item.Department.DepartmentName;
}

db.SubmitChanges();
```

**However**
You probably already know this, but it might be better to normalise your database, so that the department name is *only* on the department table, and use your employee->department relationship to get the department name for a given employee.

Answer (score 0):

using `join`:

```
var employeeDept = from e in db.employees 
                  Join d in db.Depts on e.dept_id equals d.dept_id 
                  select new 
                  {Employee = e ,
                   Department = d};

foreach(var ed in employeeDept)
{
   ed.Employee.DepartmentName = ed.Department.DepartmentName;
}
db.submitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

**One of the solution is as follows:**

```
var enumEmp = employee.AsEnumerable(); 
var enumDept = dept.AsEnumerable();

var employeeDept = from empl in enumEmp 
join d in enumDept on empl.Field<int>("dept_id") equals d.Field<int>("dept_id")
select new {enumEmp = empl , enumDept = d};

foreach(var ed in employeeDept)
{
ed.enumEmp.SetField<string>("dept_name",ed.enumDept.Field<string>("dept_name"));
}
```